# Subtracting two dates in ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, date

I'm subtracting two dates in my model in this way:-

```
  def total_days
      self.to_date - self.from_date
  end
```

My date is in `Mysql  Date` (YYYY-MM-DD)format.

When displaying my date in view it is giving me `5/1` days. Even though 5 is correct it is appending `'/1'` to the days. How can i remove this. Is there any better way of doing it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

try this, for example

```
require 'date'
$ now = Date.today
$ before = Date.today + 2.days
$ difference_in_days = (before - now).to_i
```

for your solution

```
def total_days
  difference_in_days = (self.to_date - self.from_date).to_i
end
```

Comment: If you want the difference in hours you can use: `difference_in_hours = (self.to_date - self.from_date).to_f*24`

Comment: Do you know why is this necessary? Or what data type is the date substraction? Regards.

Answer (score 3):

You can also work in the view with:

```
<%= distance_of_time_in_words(contract['start_date'], contract['end_date'])%>
```

Comment: Better answer. Thanks